# Cleaning orphaned files out of GridFS

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, gridfs

I have a collection referencing GridFS files, generally 1-2 files per record. The collections are reasonably large - about 705k records in the parent collection, and 790k GridFS files. Over time, there have become a number of orphaned GridFS files - the parent records were deleted, but the referenced files weren't. I'm now attempting to clean the orphaned files out of the GridFS collection.

The problem with an approach like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684561/gridfs-clean-out-all-unreferenced-files) is that combining the 700k records into a single large list of ids results in a Python list that's about 4mb in memory - passing that into a $nin query in Mongo on the fs.files collection takes literally forever. Doing the reverse (get a list of all ids in fs.files and querying the parent collection to see if they exist) also takes forever.

Has anybody come up against this and developed a faster solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, let's take the time to consider what [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) **actually** is. And as a starter, lets read from the manual page that is referenced:

> GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document [size limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size) of 16MB.

So with that out of the way, and that may well be your use case. But the lesson to learn here is that [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) is not **automatically** the "go-to" method for storing files.

What has happened here in your case (and others) is because of the "driver level" **specification** that this is (and MongoDB itself does **no** magic here), Your "files" have been "split" across two collections. One collection for the main reference to the content, and the other for the "chunks" of data.

Your problem (and others), is that you have managed to leave behind the "chunks" now that the "main" reference has been removed. So with a large number, how to get rid of the orphans.

Your current reading says "loop and compare", and since MongoDB **does not do joins**, then there really is no other answer. But there are some things that can help.

So rather than run a huge `$nin`, try doing a few different things to break this up. Consider working on the reverse order, for example:

```js
db.fs.chunks.aggregate([
    { "$group": { "_id": "$files_id" } },
    { "$limit": 5000 }
])
```

So what you are doing there is getting the **distinct** "files_id" values (being the references to `fs.files` ), from all of the entries, for 5000 of your entries to start with. Then of course you're back to the looping, checking `fs.files` for a matching `_id`. If something is not found, then **remove** the documents matching "files_id" from your "chunks".

But that was only 5000, so **keep** the **last** id found in that set, because now you are going to run the same aggregate statement again, but differently:

```js
db.fs.chunks.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "files_id": { "$gte": last_id } } },
    { "$group": { "_id": "$files_id" } },
    { "$limit": 5000 }
])
```

So **this works** because the `ObjectId` values are [**monotonic**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) or "ever increasing". So all **new** entries are always *greater than* the last. Then you can go an loop those values again and do the same deletes where not found.

Will this "take forever". Well **yes**. You *might* employ [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) for this, but **read** the documentation. But overall, this is the price you pay for using **two** collections.

Back to the start. The [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) spec is **designed** this way because it *specifically wants to* work around the 16MB limitation. But if that is **not** your limitation, then question **why** you are using [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) in the first place.

MongoDB has **no problem** storing "binary" data within any element of a given BSON document. So you **do not need** to use [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) just to store files. And if you had done so, then **all** of your updates would be completely "atomic", as they only act on **one** document in **one** collection at a time.

Since [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/) **deliberately** splits documents across collections, then if you use it, then you live with the pain. So use it if you **need** it, but if you do **not**, then just store the `BinData` as a normal field, and these problems go away.

But at least you have a better approach to take than loading everything into memory.

Comment: I should specify - it's not orphaned chunks that I'm cleaning up, it's the files (since pymongo takes care of the chunks when deleting a gridfs file). The original collection ("entries") refer to the GridFS files ("fs.files"). There are some good ideas here, but they're sadly not applicable because the files I'm cleaning are not necessarily contiguously missing (most of the time they're not).

Comment: @Murodese Same deal applies. Just reverse the case. At any rate you have a method to reduce the working set by utilizing the *monotonic* nature of the `ObjectId` keys. And there is no **magic tonic** here. You have created a lot of "mismatching entries" across collections. You are **stuck** with looping to compare. Your "not contiguous" statement does not make much sense in this context. There is no other way than to compare the "mismatch".

Answer (score 0):

Would like to add my bit to this discussion. Depending on size of difference, you may find it reasonable first to find identities of files, you have to keep first, and than remove chunks, that should not be kept. It may happen when you are managing huge amounts of temporary files.

In my case we have quite an amount of temporary files beeing saved to GridFS on daily basis. We currently have somewhat like 180k temporary files and a few nontemporary. When expiration index hits, we end up with approx. 400k orphans.

Useful thing to know when trying to find those files is that ObjectID is based on timestamp. As so, you can narrow your searches between dates, but enclosing range on `_id` or `files_id`.

To start looking for files i start with a loop on dates like this:

```
var nowDate = new Date();
nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate()-1);

var startDate = new Date(nowDate);
startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth()-1) // -1 month from now

var endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1); // -1 month +1 day from now

while(endDate.getTime() <= nowDate.getTime()) {
    // interior further in this answer
}
```

Inside I am creating variables to search in range of IDs:

```
var idGTE = new ObjectID(startDate.getTime()/1000);
var idLT = new ObjectID(endDate.getTime()/1000);
```

and collecting to variable IDs of files, that does exists in collection `.files`:

```
var found = db.getCollection("collection.files").find({
    _id: {
        $gte: idGTE,
        $lt: idLT
    }
}).map(function(o) { return o._id; });
```

For now I have approx 50 IDs in `found` variable. Now, to remove hight amount on orphans in collection of `.chunks`, I am loop-searching for 100 IDs to remove as long, as I found nothing:

```
var removed = 0;
while (true) {

    // note that you have to search in a IDs range, to not delete all your files ;)
    var idToRemove = db.getCollection("collection.chunks").find({
        files_id: {
            $gte: idGTE, // important!
            $lt: idLT,   // important!
            $nin: found, // `NOT IN` var found
        },
        n: 0 // unique ids. Choosen this against aggregate for speed
    }).limit(100).map(function(o) { return o.files_id; });

    if (idToRemove.length > 0) {

        var result = db.getCollection("collection.chunks").remove({
            files_id: {
                $gte: idGTE, // could be commented
                $lt: idLT,   // could be commented
                $in: idToRemove // `IN` var idToRemove
            }
        });

        removed += result.nRemoved;

    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

and afterwards increment dates to get closer to current:

```
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()+1);
```

One thing I can't solve for now is that removing operation is taking quite some time. Finding and removing chunks based on `files_id` takes 3-5s per ~200 chunks (100 unique ids). Probably I have to create some smart index to make finds quicker.

## Improvement

Packed it into "small" task, that is creating deletion process on mongo server and disconnects. It is obviously a JavaScript, you can send to mongo shell on eg. daily basis:

```
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()-3) // from -3 days

var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate()-1); // until yesterday

var idGTE = new ObjectID(startDate.getTime()/1000);
var idLT = new ObjectID(endDate.getTime()/1000);

var found = db.getCollection("collection.files").find({
    _id: {
        $gte: idGTE,
        $lt: idLT
    }
}).map(function(o) { return o._id; });

db.getCollection("collection.chunks").deleteMany({
    files_id: {
        $gte: idGTE,
        $lt: idLT, 
        $nin: found,
    }
}, {
    writeConcern: {
        w: 0 // "fire and forget", allows you to close console.
    }
});
```

Comment: I assume this only works if all the file `_id`'s were made using a timestamp to begin with, right?   Or, does Mongo use timestamps for all auto-generated IDs behind the scenes, and your solution leverages that fact?

Comment: Last time I checked, all IDs were generated based on microtimes, at least on system I was working. Also mongo was very efficient in searching documents using this way of filtering. Therefore remember, this answer is years old, so worth double checking

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Using distinct has a 16MB limitation so this may not work if you have a lot of different chunks. In that case you can limit the distinct operation to a subset of UUIDs.

```
/* 
 * This function will count orphaned chunks grouping them by file_id.
 * This is faster but uses more memory.
 */
function countOrphanedFilesWithDistinct(){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var orphanedFiles = [];
    db.documents.chunks.distinct("files_id").forEach(function(id){
        var count = db.documents.files.count({ "_id" : id });
        if(count===0){
            orphanedFiles.push(id);
        }
    });
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    var time = stop-start;
    print("Found [ "+orphanedFiles.length+" ] orphaned files in: [ "+time+"ms ]");
}

/*
 * This function will delete any orphaned document cunks.
 * This is faster but uses more memory.
 */
function deleteOrphanedFilesWithDistinctOneBulkOp(){
    print("Building bulk delete operation");
    var bulkChunksOp = db.documents.chunks.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    db.documents.chunks.distinct("files_id").forEach(function(id){
        var count = db.documents.files.count({ "_id" : id });
        if(count===0){
            bulkChunksOp.find({ "files_id" : id }).remove();
        }
    });
    print("Executing bulk delete...");
    var result = bulkChunksOp.execute();
    print("Num Removed: [ "+result.nRemoved+" ]");        
}
```